# Express post route in vercel not working?

Tags: node.js, express, vercel

I am trying to create a post route in my express vercel app but I keep getting 404
This is the part of my index.js which creates the route

```
app.post('/ap', function (req,res) {
  
    let body = req.body
    
    console.log(body); }) 
   
      res.status(200).send({"message:":"request received"})
      console.log("b")
      console.log(typeof body)
  })
```

Here is my vercel.json file

```
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/ap/(.*)", "destination": "/ap" }]
}
```

Can someone help me fix my index.js \ vercel.json file

Answer (score 0):

I found some syntax error:

```js
app.post('/ap', function (req, res) {

  let body = req.body

  console.log(body)

res.status(200).send({ "message:": "request received" })
console.log("b")
console.log(typeof body)
  })
```